# mysql query on equal values in a column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
| id | title    | parent |
------------------------
|  1 | example  |   0    |
|  2 | example2 |   2    |
   3   example3     3
   4   example4     2
   5   example5     2
```

How can I make a query  in function of title field to get back all the row where parent_id's values are equal.

example: show all rows having the same `parent` as the row which matches `title="example2"`.

should give back

```
2 | example2 | 2
4 | example4 | 2
5 | example5 | 2
```

Comment: if title="example2" then why do u want id 4 and 5 ??

Comment: @sujal because they're related to the same parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only have the `title` as argument and want all the rows that are related to the same `parent_id` you may utilize a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE parent IN (SELECT parent FROM tbl WHERE title = "example2")
```

or you can basically achieve the same using a [self-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join):

```
SELECT related.* 
FROM tbl source
LEFT JOIN tbl related ON source.parent = related.parent
WHERE source.title = "example2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing:

If you want the results where parent is 2 then use (As mattytommo suggests):

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE parent = 2
```

If you want the results where the parent is equal to id then use:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id = parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say "give me all rows that have the same parent id as my matching row", which would be this query:

```
select t2.*
from table t1
join table t2 on t2.parent = t1.parent
where t1.title = 'example2'
```

Comment: i guess t1 and t2 should be aliases to the same table (self-join).. if so, you should declare them as such (or add a view 't2' to the database that reflects `SELECT * FROM t1`)